# PY3MQI. AMQ9627 when use sco.CertificateLabel and os user does not match certificate label user

Tags: python, docker, ibm-mq, openshift-3, pymqi

Original issue: https://github.com/dsuch/pymqi/issues/181

Hello!

My MQ client version is 9.0.0.3-IBM-MQC-LinuxX64
Applications works in container, orchestra is Openshift 3.0.

**Cert reqs was created by the following command:**

```
runmqckm -certreq -create -db od99usr.kdb -pw pw -label ibmwebspheremqod99usr -dn dn -size 2048 -file od99usr.csr -sig_alg SHA256WithRSA
```

**Part of code from my application:**

```
key_repo_location = settings.MQ_KEY_REPO_LOCATION
conn_info = "%s(%s)" % (host, port)
ssl_cipher_spec = 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256'
cd = pymqi.CD()
cd.ChannelName = channel
cd.ConnectionName = conn_info
cd.ChannelType = pymqi.CMQC.MQCHT_CLNTCONN
cd.TransportType = pymqi.CMQC.MQXPT_TCP
cd.SSLCipherSpec = ssl_cipher_spec
cd.CertificateLabel = "ibmwebspheremqod99usr"
# SCO
sco = pymqi.SCO()
sco.CertificateLabel = "ibmwebspheremqod99usr"
sco.KeyRepository = key_repo_location
```

**Whoaim from container:**

```
whoami
whoami: cannot find name for user ID 1007400000
```

**when I trying to connect I get the following python error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 385, in trace_task

    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 648, in __protected_call__

    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/code/base/tasks.py", line 22, in get_create_incident_results

    mq = MQConnection()

  File "/code/base/mq.py", line 39, in __init__

    self.qmgr.connect_with_options(queue_manager, cd, sco)

  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymqi/__init__.py", line 1412, in connectWithOptions

    raise MQMIError(rv[1], rv[2])

pymqi.MQMIError: MQI Error. Comp: 2, Reason 2381: FAILED: MQRC_KEY_REPOSITORY_ERROR
```

In /var/mqm/errors/*log I have:

```
----- amqxfdcx.c : 891 --------------------------------------------------------
04/21/2020 03:27:36 PM - Process(37.1) User(UNKNOWN) Program(celery)
                    Host(sdsa-47-4rgwt) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.0.0.3) QMgr(.)

AMQ9627: The path and stem name for the SSL key repository have not been
specified.

EXPLANATION:
The directory path and file stem name for the SSL key repository have not been
specified. On a MQ client system there is no default location for this file.
SSL connectivity is therefore impossible as this file cannot be accessed.
ACTION:
Use the MQSSLKEYR environment variable or MQCONNX API call to specify the
directory path and file stem name for the SSL key repository.
```

Can you explain me where is my mistake?
I also tried to change 
`sco.CertificateLabel` to "od99usr"
remove and add `cd.CertificateLabel`
but get the same error =(

EDIT:

```
$ oc rsh pod
echo $HOME; ls -ls $HOME
/
total 0
0 lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root    root      7 Sep 19  2018 bin -> usr/bin
0 dr-xr-xr-x.   2 root    root      6 Dec 14  2017 boot
0 drwxrwxrwx.   1 od99usr od99usr  69 Apr 21 19:09 code
0 drwxr-xr-x.   5 root    root    360 Apr 21 19:08 dev
0 drwxr-xr-x.   1 root    root     66 Apr 21 19:08 etc
0 drwxr-xr-x.   2 root    root      6 Sep 19  2018 home
0 lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root    root      7 Sep 19  2018 lib -> usr/lib
0 lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root    root      9 Sep 19  2018 lib64 -> usr/lib64
0 drwxr-xr-x.   2 root    root      6 Dec 14  2017 media
0 drwxr-xr-x.   2 root    root      6 Dec 14  2017 mnt
0 drwxr-xr-x.   1 root    root     17 Apr 21 13:33 opt
0 drwxr-xr-x.   3 od99usr root     21 Apr 21 13:36 oracle
0 dr-xr-xr-x. 391 root    root      0 Apr 21 19:08 proc
0 dr-xr-x---.   1 root    root     23 Sep 19  2018 root
0 drwxrwxrwx.   1 root    root     23 Apr 21 19:08 run
0 lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root    root      8 Sep 19  2018 sbin -> usr/sbin
0 drwxr-xr-x.   2 root    root      6 Dec 14  2017 srv
0 dr-xr-xr-x.  13 root    root      0 Aug 30  2019 sys
0 drwxrwxrwx.   1 root    root     73 Apr 21 19:10 tmp
0 drwxr-xr-x.   1 root    root     19 Sep 19  2018 usr
0 drwxr-xr-x.   1 root    root     39 Apr 21 13:33 var
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the reference to the key repository.  The program produced the following error:

```
pymqi.MQMIError: MQI Error. Comp: 2, Reason 2381: FAILED: MQRC_KEY_REPOSITORY_ERROR
```

And the `AMQERR01.LOG` showed this:

```
AMQ9627: The path and stem name for the SSL key repository have not been
specified.
```

Review the sample provided on the pymqi Git hub repository [pymqi/code/examples/ssl_tls.py](https://github.com/dsuch/pymqi/blob/master/code/examples/ssl_tls.py), this hows how to specify the location of the key repository:

```py
key_repo_location = '/var/mqm/ssl-db/client/KeyringClient'

...

sco = pymqi.SCO()
sco.KeyRepository = key_repo_location

qmgr = pymqi.QueueManager(None)
qmgr.connect_with_options(queue_manager, cd, sco)
```

So in your code above you do reference this, but I don't see that you set the `key_repo_location` to any value.

```
sco.KeyRepository = key_repo_location
```

Comment: I don't include assignment of that variable in my part of code. It is exactly exists. When I use od99usr with that code everything is OK.

Comment: Can you show your `connect_with_options line`?  Also `CertificateLabel` is a `CD` property not a `SCO` property, can you remove this line `sco.CertificateLabel = "ibmwebspheremqod99usr"` and leave this line `cd.CertificateLabel = "ibmwebspheremqod99usr"`

Comment: Also can you try this in the non-working container `echo $HOME; ls -ld $HOME`

Comment: The same error after removing from eco and appending to cd ((

queue_manager = "CLS1"
# MNGR
self.qmgr = pymqi.QueueManager(None)
self.qmgr.connect_with_options(queue_manager, cd, sco)

Comment: Can you edit and update the code in the question to reflect the current state of just having CertificateLable on the cd as well as the connect_with_options.  Also on the command I gave was specifically `ls -ld $HOME`, you provided output for `ls -ls $HOME`, can you please provide output for the command I provided?

Comment: oc set env dc/proj MQCERTLABL=ibmwebspheremqod99usr fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
cd.CertificateLabel = "ibmwebspheremqod99usr"
# SCO
sco = pymqi.SCO(Version=pymqi.CMQC.MQSCO_VERSION_5,
                KeyRepository=key_repo_location)
```

and

```
oc set env dc/proj MQCERTLABL=ibmwebspheremqod99usr
```

fix my problem

Comment: setting ENV variable `MQCERTLABL=ibmwebspheremqod99usr` and `cd.CertificateLabel = "ibmwebspheremqod99usr"` should not both be needed, likely the second one is what is in use.  If you had to specify `Version=pymqi.CMQC.MQSCO_VERSION_5` you may not be using the latest pymqi version 1.10.1.  See these pymqi issues: [170](https://github.com/dsuch/pymqi/issues/170) and [141](https://github.com/dsuch/pymqi/issues/141).  I think the issue with MQSCO Version needing to be set manually to 5 is corrected in the latest version.

Comment: Can you confirm which version of pymqi you are using?

Comment: I use py3mqi==1.6.0

Comment: py3mqi is a fork of pymqi from before pymqi supported python 3.  I suggest you get the latest pymqi 1.10.1, I think you should not need to set version or env variable.